# jQuery reload div: does it request the full page from the server or only a section?

Tags: jquery, load

I'm starting to think about diminishing the load on my server. If I use this code to reload a div, does it request the full page from the server and only modify the div? Or does the server only send the div?

```
$(".reload a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).prop('href');
  $("#test").load(url + " #test > *");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It GETs the entire page, it is jQuery that selects and returns the specified element. If the requested file is very big you can create a subview and load that instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you suggest separating my page into smaller pages so that the server only has to send these smaller pages? Is that a good way to do things?

Comment: @user2018084 Yes, I always create subviews, it makes your views more cleaner/manageable/reusable and also improves the speed of Ajax requests(_if any_).

Comment: I'm trying to find more info on the web on using subviews but can seem to find, probably because I'm not sure I know what I'm looking for. What I would like is when a user clicks a certain link, to only update the contents of one div (the contents of that div are held in a php file. ie: blah.php?var=10). I don't want my whole page to be requested, but only blah.php?var=10 to be requested and placed into that div. I would like to find a tutorial or something on this, could you point me in the right direction? What will I need to use to accomplish this?

Comment: @user2018084 Oh, sorry if my answer was confusing, by subview I just meant a different `.php` file that can be loaded in the main view using php [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function. You can also structure the file for Ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it would send the entire page - a server doesn't know about DIVs or the DOM